# No Bootable Medium Found only on Windows 7

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, iso-image

First of all, I tried to install windows 7 on my Virtualbox following some tutorials and documentation. but I can't seem to find any workaround to my error which is `No Bootable Medium Found`. I already put up the ISO on `Controller: SATA` since I could not find the IDE one when it first created like this

[image]]

The ISO works fine with VMware but not with the virtual box as I'm right now really need it very much. also, i remember to manage the boot order device like this
[image]

I also tried to enable and disable the EFI option. but EFI only provides an empty terminal without anything happening. there's nothing there but `shell>`. I cannot figure out anymore what could be the problem since it's all covered up in any other question here at superuser or other VM forum. I hope someone could enlighten me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Click on the 'windows.iso' CD as seen in your screenshotted Storage menu. There should be a box that you can tick to make it recognised as a Live CD/DVD. Once that box is ticked, your VM should be able to boot from the iso.